Calculating a column using other columns on The same table
Saving(accountNum, interestRate, bal)
For savings accounts and interest equivalent to the balance multiplied by
the interest rate is added to the account on the first of every month.
Please enforce that in sql oracle.
Tried using Triger but apparently I don't have the privileges and no sub queries are allowed in the sql oracle of the school. Also said I couldn't reference other colums. Eg bal = (interestRate * balbalance) +balance

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use an UPDATE statement.
UPDATE saving
SET balance = balance * (1 + interestRate);

Run it every month at midnight of the first day of the month.
If necessary, put it into a scheduled job:
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
   job_name        => 'AddInterest'
  ,start_date      => ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1)
  ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1'
  ,end_date        => NULL
  ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
  ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
  ,job_action      => 'UPDATE saving SET balance = balance * (1 + interestRate);'
  ,enabled         => TRUE
);


You could try through the eagle. But the answer above is more ideal.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
